# "Expected an expression" error when trying to use va_arg

Tags: c, variadic-functions

I'm trying to use va_arg to assign the value of an argument to a variable. The code compiles but does not work as intended. When I try to debug with vscode (Debug C/C++ File) I get that error.

```
void    ft_printf_char(specifier *fmt)
    {
        const char  c = va_arg(fmt->args, int);
        ft_putchar_fd(c, 1);     
    }

static char *parse_format_specifier(char *str, specifier *fmt)
    {
        if (*str == 'c')
            ft_printf_char(fmt);
        return (++str);
    }

int ft_printf(const char *str, ...)
    {
        int return_value;
        specifier fmt;
    
        return_value = 0;
        va_start(fmt.args, str);
        while (*str)
            if (*str == '%' && *str++)
            {
                str = parse_format_specifier((char *)str, &fmt);
            }
            else
            {
                return_value++;
                ft_putchar_fd(*str++, 1);
            }
        va_end(fmt.args);
        return_value += fmt.len;
        return return_value;
    }
```

// in another file

```
#ifndef FT_PRINTF_H
# define FT_PRINTF_H

#include <stdarg.h>

typedef struct specifier
{
    int         len;
    va_list     args;

}   specifier;


int ft_printf(const char *str, ...);
void    ft_printf_char(specifier *fmt);


#endif
```

// main.c

```
void main()
{
    ft_printf("print char %c", 'c');
}
```

I have no idea what the error message means. The thingy that warns you about errors on the editor says

```
#define va_arg(ap,type) __builtin_va_arg(ap, type)
Expands to:

__builtin_va_arg(fmt->args, int)
expected an expressionC/C++(29)
```

Maybe there's syntax error that I can't find?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/variadic/va_arg. There's an example of how to use it. The way you use it is wrong.

Comment: @CristiFati How is it wrong? Having it as a member of a struct is certainly weird, but I don't see anything that says that isn't allowed.

Comment: I can't reproduce the warning by the way: https://godbolt.org/z/6MqGfW5s4. What compiler are you using?

Comment: @Kevin: There are no variadic arguments involved (in the provided code). Also, types don't match. [\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @CristiFati A `va_list` already exists, presumably from `ft_printf` (which I imagine creates a `specifier` struct and calls `ft_printf_char` with it). Assuming `fmt->arg` is a valid `va_list` (we can't tell from the code posted), there's nothing wrong with `va_arg(fmt->args, int);` It certainly isn't a syntax error.

Comment: And what types don't match? `const char` and `int`? That doesn't matter, as the `int` will be converted to a `char` for the assignment.

Comment: @kevin `ft_printf` indeed creates a struct and calls a function that calls `ft_printf_char`. I've edited the question with the missing code. I've no idea what compiler I'm using. When I compile with gcc, no errors are displayed, when I try to run or debug the code with the play button on vscode, that's when I get "expected an expression"

Comment: Not an answer to the quyestion, but do note that `*str == '%' && *str++`  evaluates to nonzero in exactly the cases where `*str == '%'` alone evaluates to nonzero.  I suspect you meant `*str == '%' && *++str`, instead.  But really, you ought to move the increment out of the condition, both for clarity and for better handling of format strings that end with a `%` character.

Comment: "expected an expression" would be a diagnostic from a compiler, so vscode must be compiling the code for you when you try to run it.  That's not unreasonable.  But it's using a compiler that doesn't like your code (evidently not gcc).

Comment: The return type of `main()` should be `int`, not `void`.

Comment: ... and that's the only actual error I see in your code.  Furthermore, if I fix that and supply a suitable `ft_putchar_fd()` function then the code overall compiles for me without any diagnostics (gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic) and works as appears to be intended.  If you have a compiler that rejects it then that compiler is buggy or otherwise broken.

Comment: `__builtin_va_arg` is a function used internally by gcc, but the error message "expected an expression" doesn't look like gcc's style.  Could this be an installation problem, where you have one compiler using headers intended for a different one?  How did you install and set up your compiler environment?